# React JS : React Select Dropdown position to top if there is no space below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-select

I am using [React Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select)

I want its Dropdown position to be dynamic. let's say if there is no space below it, then the dropdown should be opened to above select box.

```js
<Select
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={options}
/>
```

Is there any option to make dropdown position dynamic?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Which version of react-select are you using? v3?

Comment: I am using Version 3.1.0

Answer (score 43):

You can use `menuPlacement` option on your Select component with "bottom" (default), "top" or "auto".

You can see other props [here](https://react-select.com/props#select-props) ;)

Comment: It's usually fine to make the cheeky "check the docs ;)" comment, but the React Select docs are honestly terrible to search through.  It took me hours to find this prop

Comment: That prop doesn't work, at least for asyncs. It's an unresolved issue on their end.

Comment: That doesn't make it dynamic based on "fitting the screen"

Answer (score 22):

```
<Select
  menuPlacement="top"
  ...
/>
```

You can use `menuPlacement` prop `top`, `bottom` or `auto`

Answer (score 14):

`<Select menuPortalTarget={document.body} menuPosition={'fixed'} />`

After hours of finding the solution.This perfectly worked for me.

Comment: You save my day thanks

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking into

Comment: Wow, perfect. This answer should be the accepted one :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using `menuPlacement="auto"` and the dropdown does not drop up as you would expect, you can additionally use `minMenuHeight` to inform the dropdown when it should change, which solved this issue for me:

```
<Select 
  menuPlacement="auto"
  minMenuHeight={300}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside component:

```
render() {
    const className = this.state.dropUp ? 'drop-up' : '';

    return (
      <Select {...this.props} className={className} />
    );
  }
```

And in css file:

```
.drop-up .Select-menu-outer {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: side note: you can make state value of dropup false by window size

Answer (score 1):

If you want a native solution for this problem, use styles prop like below

```
<ReactSelect
  id="my-select"
  name="my-select"
  instanceId="my-select"
  options={mySelectOptions}
  value={mySelectValue}
  onChange={handleMySelectChange}
  
  // ATTENTION
  menuPortalTarget={typeof window !== 'undefined' ? document.body : null}
  styles={{
    menuPortal: (provided: React.CSSProperties) => ({
      ...provided,
      zIndex: 9999,
    }),
    menu: (provided: React.CSSProperties) => ({
      ...provided,
      zIndex: 9999,
      top: 'auto',
      bottom: '100%',
    })
  }}
  //

/>
```

Read more on https://react-select.com/styles

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the source code of the library and found that to make `menuPosition="absolute"` and `menuPlacement="auto"` work the closest scrollable parent (relative to which we want to position menu) must have `position: relative`. It fixed all the issues with dropdown menu positioning in my case.

It works at least in the latest version of the library (`5.8.0`).